# React Native: Crop image on Android

Tags: android, react-native, base64, crop, android-bitmap

The following function works on iOS, but doesn't work on Android. I want to achieve the same result on both platforms.

Based on [this official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore.html), the reason is missing `ImageStore` in `react-native` package for Android.

```
import {
  ImageEditor,
  ImageStore
} from 'react-native';
```

What would be an alternative way to crop images (as square) in `react-native` for Android?

```
cropImage(base64ImageData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      ImageStore.addImageFromBase64(
        base64ImageData,
        (photoURI)=>{
          ImageEditor.cropImage(
            photoURI,
            {offset:{x:0,y:(1920-1080)/2},size:{width:1080, height:1080}},
            (croppedURI)=>{
              ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(
                croppedURI,
                (base64CroppedData)=>{
                  ImageStore.removeImageForTag(croppedURI);
                  resolve(base64CroppedData);
                },
                (err)=>{
                  reject(err);
                }
              );
              ImageStore.removeImageForTag(photoURI);
            },
            (err)=>{
              reject(err);
            }
          );
        },
        (err)=>{
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

**Update:**

There is a project `https://github.com/seancunningham/react-native-image-store-ext` (last commit Oct 28, 2016), but it only [implements](https://github.com/seancunningham/react-native-image-store-ext/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dev/sekt/react_native_image_store_ext/RCTImageStoreManagerExt.java):

- Boolean removeImageForTag(String file_uri)

The rest is missing:

- static addImageFromBase64(base64ImageData, success, failure)

My preliminary solution:

```
  private static final String IMAGE_STORAGE_URL_SCHEME = "rct-image-store";

  @ReactMethod
  public void addImageFromBase64(String base64_image_data, Callback successCallback, Callback failureCallback){
    String imageStorageDir = this.reactContext.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/"+IMAGE_STORAGE_URL_SCHEME+"/";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    String file_uri = imageStorageDir+"1";
    try {
      File f = new File(imageStorageDir);
      if(!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
      }
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_uri, false);
      byte[] decodedImage = Base64.decode(base64_image_data, Base64.DEFAULT);
      fos.write(decodedImage);
      fos.close();
      successCallback.invoke("file://"+file_uri);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      failureCallback.invoke("Failed to add image from base64String"+ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      failureCallback.invoke("Failed to add image from base64String"+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

- static getBase64ForTag(uri, success, failure)

Implemented in [this file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/camera/ImageStoreManager.java) `ImageStorageManager.java`

- static hasImageForTag(uri, callback)

Comment: Did you find the solution? I encountered same problem. :)

Comment: No solution so far

Comment: Expo is working on this for months. I hope the good news come soon

Comment: @hellofanengineer did you find a better solution for this?

Comment: Nah. I pushed it to the production. Working on other projects :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be the sum of the offset + size be more then the height accepted, try it:

`{offset:{x:0,y:(1920-1080)/2},size:{width:1080, height:1080 - (1920-1080)/2)}},`

See if it works, if it does, just try to resize your size.height and see what works for you! :)